# Why are there so many Dutch tilts in Thor?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-2011

I just rewatched the first film in the *Thor* franchise, and story-wise/performance-wise, it mostly holds up. However, I was also stricken by the sheer number of [Dutch tilts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_angle) in the film. Every scene seems to have at least five versions of the angle. Why did Kenneth Branagh and DP Haris Zambarloukos make this stylistic choice?

Comment: "Donatello, are you okay? What happened? I thought you were just watching a film?" *[Lying on sofa, head back, groaning]* "So... many... Dutch... tilts!"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In the commentary track for Thor, Director Kenneth Branagh says that the dutch angles in the film were inspired by the style of comic books.

> They were there because that’s how I received the dynamism of the
>   composition in the frames, wide angle lenses with lots of depth. 
>   That’s why I chose that type of style for this.

Zambarloukos backed this up in [an interview](https://theasc.com/ac_magazine/June2011/Thor/page1.html) he gave to the American Society of Cinematographers.

> We also made very liberal use of Dutch angles throughout Thor.
>   The wider camera would be Dutched one way, the close would
>   be Dutched the opposite, and we’d flip that for the reverse shots. It
>   was a kind of interpretation of the comic-book style.